# PIC16F887 PWM multiple output

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm, xc8

I am trying to design a control for a BLDC motor with a PIC16F887.

I have managed to activate a PWM output and be able to vary it with a potentiometer.
The point is, I need to get 6 PWM signals out.

When I change the CCP1CON I can vary the PWM output but it is always one.

I attach the part of my code where I configure the PWM.

```
void PWM_Initialize()
{
  PR2 = ("%#x", (_XTAL_FREQ/(PWM_freq*4*TMR2PRESCALE)) - 1);
  CCPR1L = 0x1F; 
  RC1 = 0; 
  RC2 = 0;    
  T2CON = 0x03;    
  CCP1CONbits.CCP1M = 0b1100;
  CCP1CONbits.P1M = 0b00;
  TMR2 = 0;
  T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1; //Timer 2 ON     
}
```

How can I activate multiple PWM outputs?

Comment: You've chosen the wrong micro for this job. Your PIC16F877 only has 1 PWM module.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for your answer.
I have seen examples with this PIC16F887 where they generate 6 PWM signals.
How do they do that?
With the TIMER?
It is a great question that I have.

Comment: Please cite the examples so we can discuss - otherwise we can only speculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Controller has got only 2 PWM outputs. The PIC16F1783 could maybe help you.